# Facebook - logout with no access token

Tags: facebook, oauth, access-token

If a user cancels when asked to give permission for an app - which then does not enable me to get an access token - how can I log out without having an access token?

The reason I was to do this is because this is being used in a public kiosk and I would like the user to not remain logged in if they cancel - which is what is happening now.

I am attempting to do all this via url requests.

Thank you.

Comment: _“how can I log out without having an access token”_ – you can’t. (And FB.logout as mentioned in the answer won’t work either AFAIK.) The need for an active user access token is simple – otherwise _any_ site on the web could log me out of Facebook, without me wanting that to happen.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the reply. I was reading in the Facebook docs [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) - this bit of info:

There is another method to make calls to the Graph API that doesn't require using a generated app token. You can just pass your app id and app secret as the access_token parameter when you make a call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret`

The choice to use a generated access token vs. this method depends on where you hide your app secret.

Is this an option? Not working for me. Thanks.

Comment: The combination `app_id|app_secret` is an app access token (one that always works, and it is also how the PHP SDK creates the app access token internally). Whether you use that or the (different) app access token you can get from calling the endpoint they have for that – an app access token should never be used in client-side code where it could be spotted by the user. And I don’t think the app access token works for logging out – it has to be an active user access token, for the reason described above.